# Does Div inherits parents properties by default

Tags: jquery, html

Just wondering if div actually inherits properties from it's parent div, for example,

```
<div id = "pDiv" style="display:none;"> 
   <div id = "cDiv" style="display:none;"> 
      <h2> Abc</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

when i check `alert($("#cDiv").css('visibility'))` i get result as "Visible", ummm but in real it's hidden..

How can i check if child div is actually visible on screen or not.

Comment: Check using: `$('#cDiv').is(':visible')` BTW, `visibility` property and `display` one are not the same

Comment: `visibility` and `display` are non-related, setting one to something won't change the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not check bananas while waiting for potatoes!

```
alert($("#cDiv").css('visibility'))
```

Returns you `css` property `visibility` which **is** `visible` by default, and you should look for `display` property.

```
alert($("#cDiv").css('display'))
```

Or, if you wish to check for *real* `visibility`, just run:

```
alert($("#cDiv").is(':visible'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    $('#cDiv').is(':visible')
```

or

```
    $( "#cDiv:visible" )
```

Comment: I guess for checking purpose, you mean for second one: `$( "#cDiv:visible" ).length`

Comment: Yea, it would return true/false, which can serves the same purpose as that of .is(':visible')

Answer (score 1):

You need to use block or inline-block as display but not visible for visibility:

```
<div id = "pDiv" style="display:none;"> 
   <div id = "cDiv" style="visibility:visible;"> <!--will hidden as it's parent is hidden-->
      <h2> Abc</h2>
   </div>
</div>


<div id = "pDiv" style="display:none;"> 
   <div id = "cDiv" style="display:block;"> <!--will now show the div-->
      <h2> Abc</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, this works `alert($("#cDiv").css('display'));`